# What high available architecture for IBM Cognos?

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

Forgive my basic question, but i'm looking for a high available architecture for IBM Cognos 11.x ?

I came accross some definitions, with 2 Gateways, multiple dispatchers and one content store. But i didn't find it convenience.

Thank you for your help, i appreciate it.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the requirements?  Is it high availability you want from the services (i.e. Cognos Application Server) or is it actually the data source being queried (IBM power system with DB2 database, etc)

Comment: Where did you "come across" the definitions?  I'd hate to lead you back to the same page that didn't help you.

Comment: Hey, i appreciate your quick response.
Our need was a High Available architecture for the Application Tier, to provide a continuous availability and load balancing.
We ended up making two identical cognos servers, each one included the gateway, application tier, and the data tier, but pointing on the same database, using an external load balancer for requests forwarding. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two potential issues with your deployment of two complete Cognos installs behind a load balancer:

1. Any user-generated report/dashboard/story content will only exist on one environment.
2. There could be some corner cases with stateful interactions that don't work, such as paging through long report output. This could be mitigated using session affinity load balancing, but failover might not be clean.

The standard way of implementing fault tolerance is a single Cognos environment with redundancy for both content manager and application tier:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/c_reportnetinstallationoptions.html

This requires a minimum of 4 servers - 2 content managers and 2 application tiers. In this configuration only 1 content manager is active. Content manager failover is not necessarily invisible to users.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your answer is very usefull, i think this will solve our problem.